# Java: Printing a message before forced program termion ation

Tags: java

I am running a program in java-eclipse and and I want at some point to force Termination, by clicking the terminate button.

How can I print the values of some variables, just before termination?

Thanks

Comment: What is the terminate button? in eclipse you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.exit();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) can be used for terminates the JVM. Your application would exit anyway at the same spot in the code.

if `exit` is a button

```
exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know that he is using swing?

Comment: @nachokk he just mention that when click on button will need to cause termination. So i guess he is works on swing.

Comment: Acctually was working with a huge set of data, coming from an endpoint, and for testing purposes, i only wanted to see where i was at, after some seconds. The data I was receiving was sort of infinite ( I was querying dbpedia's endpoint:) )

Answer (score 1):

You could register a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do some stuff before exiting
    }
}));
```

As per javadoc:

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start
>   all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them
>   run concurrently.

Comment: this it's work if he terminates the process with the eclipse terminate button? i test it in netbeans and doesn't work.

Comment: @nachokk Indeed, I've tested this in IntelliJ, and hook won't run if the JVM was terminated by pressing the stop button. If the program terminates normally, or via `System.exit()` with any exit code, hook is launched.